# Kubernetes deployment without resources requests/limits

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

How does Kubernetes schedule deployments that don't define memory or cpu request/limit?

i.e. spec.containers[].resources is missing from the deployment.

When calling `kubectl describe node node_name` on a node running such pod the resources section displays the following:

```
Name       CPU Requests CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
Pod_Name       0 (0%)      0 (0%)       0 (0%)         0 (0%)
```

What does it mean?

I couldn't find any documentation.

Some Helm chart default configuration are missing the resources section and I don't know what is the effect.

Comment: I know, It's not mandatory to specify your CPU and Memory Utilization limit in your deployments.

Answer (score 4):

If a container `requests` a resource, Kubernetes will only schedule it on a node that can give it that resource. `Limits`, on the other hand, make sure a container never goes above a certain value. The container is only allowed to go up to the `limit`, and then it is restricted.

Without any mention of `requests` and `limits` a pod can get scheduled to a node which does not have resources to satisfy's the pods need and the pod can get killed when no more resource is available in the node.

The output is showing `0` because there is no `requests` and `limits` in the deployment yaml.